# Arrays.sort a List<E>

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have the following code

```
List<Test> list= new ArrayList<Test>();
list.add(t1);
list.add(t2);
Arrays.sort(list);
```

Class Test implements Comparable but I get the error at Arrays.sort(list) *The method sort(int[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (List)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `Collections.sort(list)`. `Arrays.sort()` is for sorting Arrays and not  `List` (or) `ArrayList`.

Since your `list` is a collection too, you can use the `Collections.sort()` method.

```
List<Test> list= new ArrayList<Test>();
list.add(t1);
list.add(t2);
Collections.sort(list); // This will sort you list
Collections.sort(list, withYourCustomComparator); // This will sort you list based on your custom comparator
```

Comment: he is asking about `List` not `ArrayList`

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi - Look at his code. Its of type `List` but `List` is an interface only. The instance created there is that of an `ArrayList` only.

Answer (score 5):

`Arrays.sort(array[]);` sorts an Array, not a list.

Try `Collections.sort(list);`.

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays.sort` expects `Array` not a collection object. You are looking for `Collections.sort`